# The error is Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub btntambah_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btntambah.Click
    Dim n As Integer
    For n = 0 To lv1.Items.Count - 1
        If lv1.Items(n).Text = txtkdbrng.Text Then
            MsgBox("Data Buku Sudah Ada Dalam List")
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next
    lv1.Items.Add(txtkdbrng.Text)
    lv1.Items(n).SubItems.Add(txtnmbrng.Text)
    lv1.Items(n).SubItems.Add(txtharga.Text)
    lv1.Items(n).SubItems.Add(txtjmlhhrg.Text)
    lv1.Items(n).SubItems.Add(txttotal.Text)
    lv1.Items(n).SubItems.Add(txtjmlpsn.Text)
    lv1.Items(n).SubItems.Add(txtspesifikasi.Text)
    txttotal.Text = Format(CDbl(Total()), "###, ###, ###")
    ClearBarang()
    txtkdbrng.Focus()
End Sub

Function Total() As Double
    Dim ttl As Double = 0
    If Not Double.TryParse(txttotal.Text, Total) Then
        Total = 0
    End If
End Function

Private Sub btncetak_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btncetak.Click
    If txtnosph.Text = "" Or lv1.Items.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox("Data Belum Lengkap", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "INFORMASI")
    Else
        Dim nilaikembali1, nilaikembali2 As Integer
        objsph.PNoSph = txtnosph.Text
        objsph.PTglSph = Format(dtpsph.Value, "yyy-MM-dd")
        objsph.PKdCs = txtkdcstmr.Text
        nilaikembali1 = objsph.Simpan()
        'menyimpan ke tabel Ada menggunakan perulangan
        For x As Integer = 0 To lv1.Items.Count - 1
            objada.PNoSph = txtnosph.Text
            objada.PKdBrg = lv1.Items(x).SubItems(1).Text
            objada.PKdBrg = CDbl(lv1.Items(x).SubItems(2).Text)
            objada.PKdBrg = CDbl(lv1.Items(x).SubItems(3).Text)
            nilaikembali2 = objada.Simpan()
            Dim objbarang As New ClsBarang
            objbarang.PKdBrg = lv1.Items(x).SubItems(0).Text
        Next
        If nilaikembali1 = 1 And nilaikembali2 = 1 Then
            MsgBox("Data Berhasil Disimpan", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "INFORMASI")
        End If
        ClearForm()
        ClearBarang()
        ClearCustomer()
        txtnosph.Text = objsph.AutoNumber
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: every time i run this program , its get problem like that. please help me , what should i do ?

Comment: WHERE do you get the problem?

Comment: Set a breakpoint in the first row of function body and run step-by-step  debugging (F10) to see what line is erroneous. Then check the var values in there and see what you are trying to convert.

Comment: The error is pretty clear.  You can't convert an empty string to a double.  Which makes sense, since an empty string has no numeric characters.  Either don't try to convert a non-numeric string to a double, or fix whatever is supplying the non-numeric string to provide a numeric one.

Comment: iam beginner for this , so i dont know where its get problem . i've tried to fix but its still get problem.

Comment: @user2956633 then you need to learn how to debug program, there's no way without it. By means of it you are able to see what's happenning on your code with every its step, also you can see current values of your variables and do many other things. Also, do google for exception texts.

Comment: @jim when i try to debugging(F10) , its that happen Private Sub FormMenu_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with this code:

```
Function Total() As Double
    Dim ttl As Double = 0
    If Not Double.TryParse(txttotal.Text, Total) Then
        Total = 0
    End If
End Function
```

First off you are using the less well known VB6 style implicit return variable that matches the name of the function, instead use the declared `Double` in your code named `ttl` and return the value, like this:

```
Function Total() As Double
    Dim ttl As Double = 0
    If Double.TryParse(txttotal.Text, ttl) Then
        Return ttl
    Else
        ' Attempted conversion of text to Double type failed
        ' Do something here, raise error, alert user, etc.
        ' Returning zero may or may not be acceptable, if it is return zero
        Return 0
    End If
End Function
```

Using the `Return` syntax produces much clearer code, in that it does not assume the reader of your code knows the implicit variable that matches the name of the function concept. Always use `Return` in a `Function`.

Note: If a total value of zero is not indicative of a problem, then you will need to alter your function to return `Nullable(Of Double)` instead of just `Double` and then you can alter the `Else` portion of the `TryParse()` result to this:

```
Function Total() As Nullable(Of Double)
    Dim ttl As Double = 0
    If Double.TryParse(txttotal.Text, ttl) Then
        Return ttl
    Else
        ' Attempted conversion of text to Double type failed
        ' So return null
        Return Nothing
    End If
End Function
```

Now the caller of your `Total` function will need to account for `Nothing` being returned and react accordingly.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answwer , i've tried but its still error. when i start debugging, that always still get problem "FormPenawaranHarga.Show()"

Answer (score 1):

This means the variable being explicitly or implicitly casted/converted to double is actually an empty string and cannot be proceed.